# Google Static Maps Api: Labels cut off

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to create a tiled grid using google static map images. I use the latitude and longitude in the middle of the tile to request the images (Math found [here](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/globalmaptiles.py)).
They line up perfectly but  whenever a label is split between two tiles, the second tile does not show the label

[Label names cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMhZz.png)

Is there any way to format the url such that the images returned are consistent with inter-tile labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is against of Terms of Service. You should be aware that stitching static maps images is prohibited in paragraph 10.5 (b) of ToS.

> No derivative works. You will not modify or create a derivative work based on any Content unless expressly permitted to do so under these Terms. For example, the following are prohibited: (i) creating server-side modification of map tiles; (ii) **stitching multiple static map images together to display a map that is larger than permitted in the Maps APIs Documentation;** or (iii) tracing or copying the copyrightable elements of Google’s maps or building outlines and creating a new work, such as a new mapping or navigation dataset.

Google recently updated Terms of services, but you can find the mentioned text in

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms-20180207#10-license-restrictions